# RegEx to find number string not enclosed in parenthesis in an alphanumeric string

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Hi I am new to regular expressions. I need an expression to use in VBA that will extract the first number string > 1 digit in length not enclosed in parenthesis in a string. For example the string:

```
"SHIRT L/S (07565) 07996 REF OR VLINE L"
```

I want 07996 from the string.

Comment: Try using the pattern `\b(\d{2,})(?!\))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only had limited success designing regex patterns on a NOT criteria but I have had better than reasonable success with removing what I don't want prior to the actual regex pattern match.

```
Function freeNums(str As String)
        Dim i As Long
        Static rgx As Object

        'prep a return error if no match
        freeNums = CVErr(xlErrNA)

        'only create the object if it has never been used before
        If rgx Is Nothing Then
            Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        End If


        'deal with the root string first and remove what we don't want to match
        'pattern for 0-9 one to nine digits in length enclosed in brackets
        rgx.Pattern = "\([0-9]{1,9}\)"
        'numbers in brackets removed
        str = rgx.Replace(str, vbNullString)

        'now look for what we actually want
        'pattern for 0-9 one to nine digits in length
        rgx.Pattern = "[0-9]{1,9}"

        If rgx.Test(str) Then
            freeNums = rgx.Execute(str).Item(0)
        End If

End Function
```

Note that to preserve the leading zero the result is returned as text. The default left alignment for text proves this. Ultimately, it would be better to return the result as a true number and format the cell as `00000`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeeped!, this one worked best for my application.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `/([0-9]{2,})(?![^\(]*\))/g`.

Second part will not match your initial pattern when it is enclosed by parenthesis.

Comment: This seems to withstand a fair bit of scrutiny.

Comment: In VBA:  `"([0-9]{2,})(?![^\(]*\))"`  The global property is set separately in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I know, it is a pain, but I can not recommend you enough to do your research on to regular expresions. I am a C#, JS kind of guy, so this is not tested in VBA, but should be a pretty good starting point:

What you want:

```
\d+(?!\()
```

*do not miss the "edit" section*

**Explanation:**

```
\d+
```

This is just matching the numbers. You can match a range (with reference to asci table) of characters in [], you could use [1-9], but there is a shortcut for a digit "\d" You want all numbers in a string which appear atleast once. You could do that using the {minimum, maximum} which would be {1,}, but there is also a shortcut for that "+" - meaning atleast once.

```
(?<!\()
```

**Negative Lookbehind**   - Says that you want a match without this prefix, not included - that is what look arounds do. This one is looking for a (, which you have to escape "\("

```
(?<= )
```

**Positive Lookbehind**  - Does the exact opposite thing, looks for matches with a specifix prefix, not included in the match. This one is looking for an empty space.

```
(?= )
```

**Positive Lookahead**  - The only difference is, that this looks in the opposite direction, meaning that it searches for postfixes, not included in the match. This one is looking again for an empty space.

```
(?! )
```

**Negative Lookahead** - I think you get it at this point, it does the exact same thing as the previous one, but negated. Of course, not included in the final match.

Finally, you could use

```
\d+(?= )(?!\()
```

just as well, given the example that you have provided, but that depends on the format of the string.

**EDIT:**
I was informed by QHarr, that VBA is very incostiontent in lookbehinds, but it supports lookahead. I am changing my solution from

```
(?<!\()(?<= )\d+(?= )(?!\()
```

TO

```
\d+(?= )(?!\()
```

**EDIT2**:

I changed the solution again from

```
\d+(?= )(?!\()
```

TO

```
\d+(?!\()
```

Because as Ron Rosenfeld suggested, that solution would not be genereral enough for "match the first bumber that is not in parentheses".The problem is, that it would not match a number at the end of the string, because of the positive lookahead looking for a space.

Comment: This seems to withstand a fair bit of scrutiny.

Comment: You require a space after the string of digits. Therefore this solution will not match digit sequences that occur at the end of the string.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That is true, I did not make it general, I have tailored it for that example that he proposed. I will edit my answer with a note.